# Get Static Resources in Session Expire - Spring Security

Tags: session, spring-security

I have a spring mvc web application where I need to get static resources (images, css files, etc) even after the session is expired. For example, I do not want to end up with session expire or invalid session error when retrieving static content after the current session is expired. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you can try the following

```
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**", "/css/**","js/**", "js/**");
    }
}
```